# devtools::use_vignette("my_package") give error

Tags: r, r-devtools

Im trying to create a vignette using the following command from Hadley Wickham's R-package book:

```
devtools::use_vignette("my_package")
```

But get the following error:

> Error: 'my_package' is not an exported object from 'namespace:devtools'

Comment: Do you have a line in your DESCRIPTION specifying `BuildVignettes: true`?

Comment: No. But I tried to add it, but still receive the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at the old version of the book at http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html.

Check out the newer version at https://r-pkgs.org/vignettes.html:

> To create your first vignette, run:
>
> ```
> usethis::use_vignette("my-vignette")
> ```

In newer versions of `devtools`, it relies on [`usethis`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/usethis/index.html) for functions like `use_vignette()`.